# Monitor remains black in BIOS menu for HP ProDesk PC

Tags: windows-7, display, bios, sleep, hp-desktop-computer

I'm trying to get in the BIOS menu of my HP ProDesk 490 G3 MT Business PC. Unfortunately, the monitor remains black until the login screen of Windows appears no matter what I try..

I've tried three different monitors, so the issue is definitely in the PC.

I've tried holding and repeating the following buttons on startup: F2; F10; F12. I have the feeling one or multiple of these buttons indeed will get me into the BIOS, because the screen remains black and I won't get the login screen anymore.

I've also tried disconnecting my SSD where Windows is installed on. I hoped it would then give an error like "Cannot find startup OS, do you want to go into the BIOS instead?", but unfortunately the screen remains black again without startup nor BIOS.

I've read somewhere the screen remaining black on startup and the startup being shorter might be due to something called Fast Boot. According to the HP manual, this is done by default for Windows 8.1+, although apparently it's also configured like this on my Windows 7 work PC in the past. I can't find anything on how to remove this Fast Boot option however..

So, how can I ensure my monitor is off sleep-mode during startup / BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways:

1. According to my research, we may not press F10 at the appropriate time, then we must restart the computer and again repeatedly press F10 when the monitor light turns green to access the utility.

Before turning on the computer, press and hold F10. Turn on the computer and continue to hold F10 until the Computer Setup (F10) Utility is displayed.

- or –

Follow the Windows instructions for rebooting the computer into the Computer Setup (F10) Utility.

2. Whether the display has a separate graphics card and integrated graphics, if there is a discrete graphics card, we try to connect the signal cable of the monitor to the interface of the discrete graphics card, and then see if we can enter the BIOS.
3. In addition to SSD, does the computer have other SSDs or HDDs? If there is, disconnect them and see if we can enter the BIOS.
4. We can call HP after-sales customer service if there are other ways to enter the BIOS.It is also possible that other key combinations enter the BIOS, like: fn + *.

Tip: There is no **fast startup** for this option in the Windows 7 operating system. The following screenshot is in windows 10 operating system.

[image]

Comment: I'm currently working at home, but tomorrow I'm back at the office again where my PC is at. I will try some of your suggested things. It indeed has both a SSD and HDD, and I only tried disconnecting the SSD where Windows is installed on. I indeed tried either pressing or holding F10 before starting the PC. And as mentioned, I have the feeling the PC does get into the BIOS, the monitor simply stays in sleep-mode, so I'm not sure a different key is the answer here. Will try some of your suggested things tomorrow and update here. Thanks for the answer!